# How to customise scrollbar of QtQuick ListView?

Tags: listview, qml, scrollbar, qtquick2

By default, the ListView control only displays a tiny scrollbar that only shows up when scrolling.

Is it possible to style this scrollbar to make it bigger? Also is it possible to make it always visible? I assume it is but unfortunately I cannot find anything about this in the doc.

Comment: Did you enable the scrollbar somehow? I dont see any scrollbar when scrolling...

Comment: @DanielBrunner, in my case it was only showing up while scrolling, and was hidden otherwise.

Comment: hah! I just missed a `ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar { }` then it worked...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ScrollBar` you are talking about is the one of `QtQuick.Controls 2.0` I suppose. [It is briefly documented here.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollbar.html)

As it inherits `Control`, it is important to also read the documentation of this baseclass, to get the knowledge about all *common properties*. You can find it [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-control.html)

Hidden inside the `ScrollBar`-Documentation (just mentioned as *"See also"*) you can find a link to [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-scrollbar). There you'll find a short example on how you might customize your `ScrollBar`

Basically, your `ScrollBar` consists out of a `background` which is the *bar* and a `contentItem` that is the *handle*. Both are just *properties*, to which you might asign your very own `Item`s. To style those `Items` you might access various properties as `active` which is used in the default-style to fade away the controls, if it is inactive. You might not do this, if you want them to be visible at all times.

Answer (score 0):

you can use contentItem and set the "implicitWidth" property in case you have a vertical scroll bar, and "implicitHeight" in case you have a horizontal scroll bar!
contentItem: Rectangle {
implicitWidth: your desired Width in pixel
implicitHeight: your desired Height in pixel
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).